# django cache issue

Tags: django

After user added a data into database, user can not find the added data in another page. then I restarted server. user can find the new data in that page. I think it's the cache problem. because if the page is already in cache. django will send the page in cash to user. but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me? Thanks so much

Comment: Please add some code where you think the caching error is

Comment: django does not automatically cache, until you specify it in `settings.py`. If you haven't specified it, then it is not django's cache framework that's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to cache, then don't use it. You need to disable the cache. Or reduce the cache timeout.

Comment: Django is like a library. It does not cache, if you don't tell django to cache. How do you, or the code you are talking about, use the cache? Maybe it uses some cache decorators. Please read the docs and try to solve your problems yourself first, then ask here.